# Open source tool to generate UML behavioral models from python code?

Tags: python, uml, reverse-engineering, state-machine, sequence-diagram

I want to generate UML behavioral models (state machines and/or sequence diagrams) from python code. Is there any open source tool that can do that?

Comment: How could an automated approach to this result in anything but a restatement of what the code already says?

Comment: It couldn't and it actually shouldn't (correctness).

Comment: My point being, a program could neither abstract over implementation details (in general) nor restate the logic in a different (equivalent, but more appropriate for some purpose) way. It seems the result would be as unnecessary as comments like `i = 0 # set i to 0`.

Comment: Maybe. My angle is actually to reverse engineer models which then I can use as case studies for my research on software modeling. It's not the code per se that I'm intersted, it's the typed attributed graphs that represent it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a [list of UML tools with code-generation or reverse engineering capabilities for python](http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#python) but I don't think any support sequence diagrams